# Decode in oracle, with multiple condition

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select decode(a.Type,1,'ONE',2,'TWO',null ,'OTHER')|| 
       Decode (b.Active, 1 ,'Yes',0,'NO', null ,'NO'),
       count(*) 
from TypeTable a,
     Status b 
where a.id=b.id 
  and a.type in(12,3,34,45,66);
```

Now question is,

I want to count those who has type 1 and other that in record
Like

```
Column1        |  Column2 
---------------+----------
One            |   10
ONE                                        
Other that ONE |   20
```

Comment: **On a side note:** Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want. Maybe you looking for something similar to my example.

```
select decode(object_type,'SYNONYM','SYNONYM','OTHER THAN SYNONYM') column1, count(*) column2 from user_objects 
group by decode(object_type,'SYNONYM','SYNONYM','OTHER THAN SYNONYM');
```

Comment: is like i want count the record,as count for 'ONE' and 'other than ONE' using decode.

Comment: select decode(a.TYPE,3,'Super','Super')  
|| decode(p.PROFILE, null, ' ','-Admin ')  
|| decode(d.Availble,'Y','YES','NO')  
|| decode(p.Active, 1, ' YES','')  as Description,count(*) 
from USERTYPE a, Config c, Details p,
Status d where c.ConfigID = a.TYPEID 
and a.TYPEID = p.ProfileID and a.TYPEID = d.TYPEID  
and a.TYPE in (3,4)  group by decode(a.TYPE,3,'XYZ','XYZ') 
,p.PROFILE ,d.Availble ,p.Active  order by decode(a.TYPE,3,'XYZ','XYZ') ,d.Availble desc;

Comment: In above query the the available values may YES/NO/Null and Active may 1/0/null so need get result like nees to count active (that is 1) and remaining (0 or null). as description